# Add row using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am printing a row with id as 'contactlist1', 'contactlist2', 'contactlist3'.... I have done this according to values stored in database. Now I want to add more row with id 'contactlist4', 'contactlist5', on button click event using jquery. Though I have taken values of variables that I am printing according to database in table. Now I wish to add row next to that id...

```
<tr id='contactlist1'>
<tr id='contactlist2'>
```

I want to add row as  `<tr id='contactlist3'>` for that I have used command

```
$("#contactlist" + k ).after(newRow);
k++;
```

k has value 3 that I have taken in variable. Is this correct to way to present id as `'contactlist3'`

Comment: Yes I think `$("#contactlist" + k )` isn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concat in $(...), try below:

```
var newContactListBase = 'contactlist';
var k = 1;
var newContactListItem = newContactListBase + k;
$("#"+ newContactListItem ).after(newRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Something else is going wrong. Perhaps jQuery isn't included or ready for the document by the time you're running your iterator?

http://jsfiddle.net/4JWPf/